# What is the difference between inbuilt qsort function and stable sort function?

Tags: c++, sorting, qsort, stable-sort

From various sources cited I know that in-built C function, stable_sort is stable but qsort is unstable. If that is the case why do we use qsort at all? Isn't it redundant? Why not use stable_sort instead?

Comment: `stable_sort` is C++ only. It is not part of the current C standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason to choose quick sort over stable sort is mostly speed: `qsort` is often faster than [`stable_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort), which should come as no surprise, because `stable_sort` comes with a stronger guarantee.

> O(N·log<sub>2</sub>(N)). If additional memory is available, then the complexity is O(N·log(N)).

Space is another consideration: `qsort` is done in place, meaning that no additional memory allocation is required. `stable_sort`, on the other hand, tries a temporary allocation of the size equal to the array being sorted.

> This function attempts to allocate a temporary buffer equal in size to the sequence to be sorted. If the allocation fails, the less efficient algorithm is chosen.

**Note from [rcgldr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3282056/rcgldr)'s comment:** (The HP / Microsoft implementation of `std::stable_sort` uses a temporary buffer 1/2 the size of the sequence. The second half is sorted into the second half of the sequence, the first half into the temporary buffer, then the temporary buffer and second half of the sequence are merged back into the sequence.

Comment: The HP / Microsoft implementation of std::stable_sort uses a temporary buffer 1/2 the size of the sequence. The second half is sorted into the second half of the sequence, the first half into the temporary buffer, then the temporary buffer and second half of the sequence are merged back into the sequence.

Comment: @rcgldr That's very smart of them! Thanks for the note, I copied it into the answer.

Comment: The HP / Microsoft std::stable_sort sorts the first half first, then the second half, then a half copy to the temp buffer is done, and the final merge is done (look like there's code to optionally do a backwards merge (from last to first), not sure if this is used or left over code). I was recalling an optimized version of this that avoids the extra copy steps. Still the key idea is using a temp buffer 1/2 size of the sequence.

Answer (score 9):

A stable sort means that the order of equal elements is preserved. This is not always required.

If it is not required, the algorithm is simpler, and sometimes faster and/or more memory-efficient.
A typical example of a stable sort algorithm is [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

Answer (score 0):

> If that is the case why do we use qsort at all?

`stable_sort()` is not part of standard C.  `qsort()` is part of standard C.

C's `qsort()` is not specified to use the quick-sort algorithm nor required to be stable nor required to be non-stable.

`qsort()` is often used as it is the the most portable.  Because `qsort()` has no specifications concerning, speed, memory efficiency and data stability, it is often encoded using a practical method for the target platform.  On an embedded platform, memory space is often more critical than speed.  On a desktop, speed likely is paramount.